# How to Multiply Two Big Numbers in Java for Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to multiply two big numbers. when user will input a number it will multiply the number with another number.But When I am trying to do it , it always shows an error.
Can you please solve this?
When I write a number as a string in "X" like String x = "554564654556" ...It always works.....
But when I use num as a string, the code fails to run in the emulator or physical device.
Here is the code.......

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText num;
    Button gen;
    TextView a,b,c;
    BigInteger mult;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        num = findViewById(R.id.num);
        gen = (Button)findViewById(R.id.gen);
        a = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a);
        b = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.b);
        c = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.c);

        gen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String x = String.valueOf(num);
                String y = "65466544554465465446";
                BigInteger m = new BigInteger(x);
                BigInteger n = new BigInteger(y);
                mult = m.multiply(n);
                String k = String.valueOf(mult);
                a.setText(k);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Note that when asking about situations that generate errors you should also post those errors so that we can see for ourselves what's happening (often the exception type, message or stacktrace has enough information to suggest a solution without having to guess).

Comment: "When I use num as a string" ... I assume you mean your `EditText num` and without knowing Android that well I assume that this class' `toString()` method does _not_ return the text or if it does it contains other characters as well. What's the value of `x`? Did you have a look at that with a debugger? As per the Javadoc on `EditText` you probably want to use [`getText()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText#getText())  to actually get the text value of that widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are tying to cast your `Edittext` to `String`. **You can't do that**.

To get the value from `Edittext`

Try like the following

```
String x = num.getText().toString();
```

Comment: I am glad that it helps you. `Happy Coding`.